# Image upload script is not working

Tags: php, upload

I have a page called addbanner.php which contains HTML and PHP script for uploading image.
but it is not working i m giving.

```
*********************************addbanner.php***************************************
   <?php
   session_start();

require_once'session.php';
require_once '../cms/config.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//for image upload part

// define the posted file into variables
//$bannerid=$_POST['bannerid'];

 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $desc=$_POST['description'];
 $dir='uploads/';
 $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
 $bits = (explode(".",$name ));
 $extension=end($bits);
 if ((($type == "image/gif")
 || ($type == "image/jpeg")
 || ($type == "image/png")
 || ($type == "image/pjpeg"))
  && ($size < 20000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
 {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
 else
  {




 //connecting the database
  $object=new connection();
  $object=$object->dbConnect();
  $st=$object->prepare("select * from banners where  file=:name");
  //$st->bindParam(1,$bannerid);
   $st->bindValue(":name",$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->execute();
  if($st->rowCount()>1)
  {
   echo "Error: Banner with this name is already exists!";
   }
    else
    {

   //$object=new connection();
  //$object=$object->dbConnect();
   $st=$object->prepare("insert into banners values('$name','$type','$size','$desc')");
   $st->execute();
     if (file_exists("uploads/" . $name))
         {
     echo $name. " already exists. ";
      }
     else
      {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir.$name);
           echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $name;
        }
          }
      }
             }
      else
          {
             echo "Invalid file";
          }
              }
      else
           {
             //HTML part
           }
         ?>
********************javascript part***************
function validate()
{
if(document.myform.file.value=='' || document.myform.description.value=='')

{
alert("Please fill all the field!");

return false;


}

  }
******************end javascript***************

*******************html form*******************
```

Banner image(Required Field)

Description(Required Field)

```
            <!-- End Form -->

                    <!-- Form Buttons -->
                    <div class="buttons" >
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
                      <input type="submit" name="cancel" class="button" value="Cancel" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Form Buttons -->
                </form>


********************end coding*****************
```

when i choose submit buttton it prints "invalid file" which is else part of script.
And there is also a problem in my javascript when i click submit leaving blank description field. It does not show alert sometimes. Please suggest something.
I simply want when user fill both the field and click submit, it will go to database and also save in a given folder.

And sorry for the incomplete script, I didn't code for cancel button yet.

Comment: This part is authentic: `<?php ?>session_start();`? If so, then I understand it doesn't work. Observing the result should tell you why

Comment: @JanDvorak I corrected the tag. Now tell me what the problem is?

Comment: @vinay Should I copy-paste one of the existing answers or expend redundant effort to find the problem independently of others? Did you notice you _do_ already have two answers on this question?

Comment: Problem is existing even after checking that asnwers. Now image is saving into uploads folder but not is database. Check my connection query and insert query that tell what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can you the following code for image upload:

```
 $image =  $_FILES['image']['name'];

  $target_path = "uploads/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
           echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded";

    }
    else
    {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

$query = "INSERT INTO imagetable values($image)";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

check out this code...

Comment: Now script is saving the image in uploads folder but no entry in database and no error regarding database.

Comment: Now how to insert record into database. Script is saving images into given uploads folder.

Comment: i have added the code to insert into database. Please see the updated code above.

Comment: My script is working fine except javascript validate function.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This- increase you file size limit - `($size < 20000)` because of this its going in else loop invalid data.

Comment: Why should i use $_SERVER ? I am using simple $dir because this is working in another script.I am working on localhost.

Comment: i already noticed that and now code is going in if() part and moving the image into uploads folder but no entry in database.

Comment: echo echo "insert into banners values('$name','$type','$size','$desc')" and copy it and try to run directly into phpmyadmin and try to find the error.

Comment: thanks to all. I found the error and now script is working fine  except a silly small error. My javascript validate() is not poping up alert even i m leaving it blank. This is last problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: TRY TO CALL VALIDATE FUNCTION LIKE THIS<form name="myform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit=" return validate();">

Comment: Okay Vikas thanks a lot. But actual is when i choose image and click submit without clicking in desc field it does not popping up. But when i focus on desc field and click submit, it pops up. Very strange for me.I know this is very minor error. But can't solve.